# COMException error: 80040154 Class not registered in microsoft.office.interop.excel.application C#

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm trying to make a application which will print some values to the excel file, for this I'm trying to use the **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** library
but whenever I try to create a object as mentioned below

`Application xlApp = new Application();`

I'm getting COM exception

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

I have Microsoft Office 365 installed in my machine and also PIA are available in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA*.

Is this right way to initalize the object.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975105/80040154-class-not-registered-exception-from-hresult).

Here is one way to proceed:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
Dim xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
[...]
```